# Possible errors in session

Tags: php, forms, session-variables, form-submit, submit-button

I just want to ask what are the possible errors in SESSION... Because I've been suffering from my bugs! My codes are  right but I don't know why it has happened that when I click the submit button it's supposed to pass the value that i declare but it always declare the last value I declared(it means I can't renew the value! once I declared my value that is permanent which is wrong because every time you click the submit it suppose to give new variable)

**home.php**

```
<form method="post" action="1home.php">
<label id="checkinD">
                    <h3>Day</h3>
                        <Input id="chiD" name="chiD" type="number" min="<?php echo $_SESSION["day_today"]; ?>" max="<?php echo $_SESSION["day_count"]; ?>" required />
            </label>
</form>

$chiD = $_POST['chiD'];
$_SESSION["chiD"] = "$chiD";
```

**1home.php**

```
<form method="post"  action="2home.php" onsubmit="return validate()">
<label id="checkinD">
                    <h3>Day</h3>
                        <Input id="chiD" name="chiD" type="text" value = " <?php echo $_SESSION["chiD"]; ?>"  readonly />
            </label>
</form>
```

BTW There is also a crazy one that occurs on my codes it's working very smoothly without logical errors but every 4 hours my codes will have logical errors without my fault!!! it's like automated bugs appeared every hour.

and sometimes to make it work I need to erase the name of my form then replace it again and typed the word that I erased. What kind of shit is this?

Comment: you missed the `action` attribute here `<form method="post" form="1home.php">`

Comment: $_SESSION["chiD"] = "$chiD"; should be $_SESSION["chiD"] = $chiD;

Comment: I try your suggestion but nothing happen :9

Comment: Where is the submit button ???????????

Comment: <input type="submit" value="FORM 2"   name="btn_form2" >

Comment: sorry i forgot this is the real one 
,
<button type="submit" value="FORM 2"   name="btn_form2" ></button>

Answer (score 0):

> PHP, you need to **session_start()** before assigning values to your
>   **session variables**. The date_today variable holds the present datetime, and date_count variable holds a random number.
>
> Though i can not see your full code but here's the working solution.

**home.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["day_today"] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$_SESSION["day_count"] = rand();
?>
<form method="post" action="1home.php">
<label id="checkinD"><h3>Day</h3></label>
     <Input id="chiD" name="chiD" type="number" min="<?php echo $_SESSION["day_today"]; ?>" max="<?php echo $_SESSION["day_count"]; ?>" required />
     <input type="submit" value="FORM 2" name="btn_form2" >
</form>
```

**home1.php**

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['chiD'])): 
$chiD = $_POST['chiD'];
$_SESSION["chiD"] = $chiD;
?>
<form method="post"  action="2home.php" onsubmit="return validate()">
<label id="checkinD"><h3>Day</h3></label>
<input id="chiD" name="chiD" type="text" value = "<?php echo $_SESSION["chiD"]; ?>"  readonly />
</form>
<?php echo "Day: ". $_SESSION['day_today']; ?>
<br>
<?php echo "Day Count: ". $_SESSION['day_count']; ?>

<?php else: ?>
<h4> Sorry! Somethinh went wrong. </h4>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Here's a screenshot of the result
[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: I try this one but nothing is happen :(

Comment: I've updated my answer. code has been tested. Hope this helps.